# Homoeomorphism between two compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

We know If that :$\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbf R^{n}$ and $\mathbf f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbf R^{m}$ is one-to-one and continuous,then $\mathbf f^{-1}$ is continuous on $\mathbf f(\Omega).$ Indeed,$\mathbf f$ is called *a homoeomorphism* from one metric space $(\Omega,d_{1})$ to another $(\mathbf f(\Omega),d_{2}).$

Metric $d_{1} (resp.d_{2})$ is Euclidean norm on $\mathbf R^{n}(resp.\mathbf R^{m})$,that is $d_{1}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=||\mathbf x-\mathbf y||=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_{i}-y_{i})^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}(resp.d_{2}(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=||\mathbf x-\mathbf y||=(\sum_{k=1}^{m}(x_{i}-y_{i})^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}).$

Now,

$(1).$Let $H\subset \Omega, $ and $H^{\circ}=H.$ If we have $[\mathbf f(H)]^{\circ}=\mathbf f(H)?$

$(2).$ Let $H\subset \Omega, $ and $\overline H=H.$  If we have $\overline{\mathbf f(H)}=\mathbf f(H)?$

Those are two similar problems.So consider$(1)$,We have for each  $\mathbf y \in \mathbf f(H)$ ,$\exists \delta(\mathbf y)>0,$s.t.$B_{\delta(\mathbf y)}(\mathbf y)\cap\mathbf f(\Omega)\subseteq \mathbf f(H)$.How can I prove there must be $r(\mathbf y)>0 ，s.t.B_{r(\mathbf y)}\subseteq \mathbf f(H)?$  $B_{\delta(\mathbf y)}(\mathbf y)$ is a open ball centered at $\mathbf y$,of radius $\delta(\mathbf y).$

Comment: In $H^{\circ}$ and $[\mathbf{f}(H)]^{\circ}$, are you taking the interior with respect to $\mathbb{R}^n$ resp. $\mathbb{R}^m$, or with respect to $\Omega$ and $\mathbf{f}(\Omega)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : Sorry,I need to mention that those take the interior with respect to $\mathbf R^{n} $   resp.$\mathbf R^{m}. $

Comment: In that case, $(1)$ doesn't generally hold. It always holds for $H = \varnothing$ of course, but by invariance of domain, in general it holds only if $m = n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer:$m=n$,because there's no homeomorphism between Euclidean spaces with different  dimensions?

Comment: Slightly stronger, there's no homeomorphism between nonempty open subsets of Euclidean spaces of different dimension. If $(1)$ holds and $\Omega$ contains a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it follows that $m = n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both. This has nothing to do with metrics. If $f$ is a homeomorphism it preserves open and closed sets (it's an open map and a closed map as well). This follows from $f^{-1}$ being continuous, as $f[A]$ is just the same as $(f^{-1})^{-1}[A]$ and being continuous means preserving inverse images of open and closed sets.

If $H^\circ = H$ then $H$ is open, so $f[H]$ is open hence $f[H]^\circ = f[H]$

If $\overline{H} = H$ then $H$ is closed so $f[H]$ is closed (easy in this case, as it is even compact!) and so $\overline{f[H]} = f[H]$.